# Formatar retorno de data com formato Date e não String

Tags: java, hibernate, data

Estou tentando retornar uma data que está gravada certa no banco (1986-04-30 17:02:00), tento converter essa data pra aparecer somente "30/04/1986", mas não adianta.

O máximo que consigo de retorno é Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 BRT 1986.

To criando a lista com Hibernate.

```
public List<Fornecedor> listarFornecedores() {
 session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
 List<Fornecedor> listaFornecedores = new ArrayList<Fornecedor>();
 query = session.createQuery("FROM Fornecedor");
 listaFornecedores = query.list();
 session.close();
 return listaFornecedores;
}
```

e no Get da Classe fornecedores tentei de tudo, mas chego no máximo até esse ponto sem dar erro:

```
public Date getInicioAtividades() throws ParseException { 
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
 String data = sdf.format(inicioAtividades);
 Date dataI = sdf.parse(data);
 return dataI;
}
```

Se fosse pra retornar uma string, tudo legal, com o `SimpleDataFormat` fica certo, porém, eu gostaria de retornar um Date. Alguém pode me dar uma força?

Comment: Acho que isso não é possivel, uma vez que em um Date sempre retorna a informação de timestamp completa. Acho que só via string mesmo. Veja esta resposta no [SOEn](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9816867/5524514)

Comment: Qual é o tipo de inicioAtividades e como vc popula ele?

Comment: Desta forma você só consegue como String. O que você pode fazer é ter dois get's, um que retorna Date e o outro que retorna String. Ex: public Date getInicioAtividades() { return inicioAtividades} public String getInicioAtividadesFormatado() { //Sua logica com o SimpleDateFormat}

Comment: Obrigado Hugo! Acho que dessa forma irá funcionar.

Comment: Mas como eu faria isso Hugo.... agora que parei pra pensar, acabei me confundindo...rs

Comment: Quando eu faço a busca, ele retornará o getInicioAtividades... como faço pra busca pegar o getInicioAtividadesFormatado?

Comment: Posta o erro ai, que se for problema de código, fica mais fácil de resolver
Tem como fazer sim, no banco salva String? se sim...
então precisa fazer fazer um converter para o hibernate ai te atende., se já esta em forma de data, então não tem problema nenhum, somente quando for mostrar usa o teu method, se salvar no banco for String e tiver a permissão de corrigir, faça isso mude para data

Comment: A ideia que deram foi fazer o seguinte, criar o seguinte método: public String getInicioFormatado() throws ParseException { SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); String data = sdf.format(inicioAtividades); return data; } mas como faço pro hibernate pegar esse kra? como obtenho o retorno? é pra inserir na classe.java né? desculpe as perguntas bobas... mas sou iniciante...rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o Hibernate 5 com o pacote do [Hibernate para Java 8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8/5.2.6.Final). Assim sendo, no seu caso, bastaria mudar o tipo do campo `inicioAtividades` e o retorno do getter para [`java.time.LocalDate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html).

Mesmo se você não puder mudar o mapeamento para `LocalDate`, nada te impede de converter o `Date` para `LocalDate`.

Veja mais sobre como usar essas classes, convertê-la de volta para `Date` ou formatar como `String`, [nesta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/177129/132).

Answer (score 0):

A forma para exibir a data do jeito que deseja é usando o SimpleDateFormat (ou outra biblioteca ou código próprio).

Note que existe uma diferença entre `java.sql.Date` (usada para gravar datas no banco e `java.util.Date`.

Veja um exemplo:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat formatoDataBanco = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    Date dataBanco = formatoDataBanco.parse("1986-04-30");
    SimpleDateFormat formatoRetorno = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    System.out.println(dataBanco);
    System.out.println(formatoRetorno.format(dataBanco));

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

A saída:

`Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 BRT 1986`

`30/04/1986`

Comment: De qualquer jeito, Date SEMPRE vai retornar um timestamp, e não apenas a data. A duvida era retornar Date somente com data e isso não é possivel sem formatar e converter pra string.

Comment: long timeStamp = 0; //timestamp da data do banco
            Date data = new Date(timeStamp);
            System.out.println(formatoRetorno.format(data));

Comment: Percebe que seja la a forma que você tente, sempre converte em string pra formatar? Como eu disse, impossivel Date retornar apenas data sem o timestamp.

Comment: Diego, o formato de saída padrão do toString() do objeto Date é esse (Wed Apr 30 00:00:00 BRT 1986), você precisa converter para outro formato.

Comment: O que to dizendo é que a pergunta foi `Formatar retorno de data com formato Date e não String` e todas as formas que você fez terminaram em string, pois não é possivel.

Comment: Se você já tem o Date, você cria uma String, se você tem a String, cria um Date. Não tem sentido criar um Date de outro Date.

Comment: Então você confirmou que sua resposta não respondeu ao que foi perguntado :)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51655/discussion-between-marcus-becker-and-diegofm).

Comment: Veja bem, você quer exibir de um objeto Date apenas o valor "30/04/1986", correto?

Comment: Eu não, o criador da pergunta. E a não ser que ele reescreva o Date só pra editar o tostring(o que seria uma besteira), não há jeito de exibir Date dessa forma.

Comment: A forma é usando o SimpleDateFormat (ou outra biblioteca ou código próprio), ou alterando o formato ISO mundial para apenas "dia/mês/ano" e obrigar todas as linguagens de programação a seguirem esse padrão.

Comment: Exato, isso que eu acho que seria legal você explicar na resposta, para que ela atenda ao que foi questionado.

Comment: Tudo isso por uma pergunta que provavelmente nem sequer será revisitada.

Comment: Agregar informação nunca é demais, e o alvo das perguntas do SOPT não são somente aqueles que fazem as perguntas. Lembre-se que este site é uma referencia na área de tecnologia para pesquisas, passar boas  informações vai muito alem de o OP voltar aqui ou não, o conteudo que você gera, quando é um bom conteudo, não serve apenas para uma pessoa.

Comment: Desculpe a demora pessoal, tive uma semana agitada. vou tentar adicionar o metodo getInicioAtividadesFormatado, indicado lá em cima, vou olhar também o recurso do java 8 que foi mencionado. Na verdade eu gostaria de ter um retorno date formatado, o máximo que consegui foi 1986-04-30, usando o gettime. Obrigado a todos pela ajuda, assim que conseguir uma forma que fique legal eu aviso aqui e digo como ficou.

Comment: A ideia que deram foi fazer o seguinte, criar o seguinte método:
    public String getInicioFormatado() throws ParseException { 
  SimpleDateFormat sdf = new                                  SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  String data = sdf.format(inicioAtividades);
  return data;
  }

mas como faço pro hibernate pegar esse kra? como obtenho o retorno? é pra inserir na classe.java né? desculpe as perguntas bobas... mas sou iniciante...rs